# Booting from Grub Rescue

Tags: grub2, bootloader

I mistakenly deleted the ubuntu partition on my machine and now I can't boot the machine. It's stuck at GRUB rescue. When I'm checking all the partitions on the hard drive using ls command, it is giving "Filesysytem is unknown" for every partition.
I wanna know can if I can boot my machine using a usb drive having ubuntu setup?

Answer (score 0):

I had linux mint and elementary os dual boot. Accidentally deleted elementary partition. So I used the bootable pen drive. Clicked on try the os without installing. Then connected another pen drive, backed up my files from the second partition. And then reinstalled the os. If you were not on dual boot. I don't know. But if you were try the above mentioned process. Incidental this happened yesterday(16.12.2016)

Comment: I had a dual boot